Wordpress and Mysql connection doesn't work with kubernetes
I have created two yaml files. One for wordpress and one for Mysql.
I can create the pods without the a problem and I can access wordpress with terminal portforwarding in my browser.
But anytime I do this it says "Error astablishing a database connection". I don't know why and I need help
I created both files with kubectl apply -f ."filename.yaml"
and I portforwarded wordpress with kubectl port-forward wordpress 8080:80
wordpress.yaml:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: wordpress
spec:
  containers:
  - name: app
    image: wordpress:latest
    env:
    - name: "WORDPRESS_DB_HOST"
      value: "mysql-service"  
    - name: "WORDPRESS_DB_NAME"
      value: "MysqlDB"
    - name: "WORDPRESS_DB_USER"
      value: "admin"
    - name: "WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD"
      value: "Test"
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80

database.yaml:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: database
  labels: 
    name: mysql-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: database
    image: mysql:latest
    env:
      - name: "MYSQL_USER"
        value: "admin"
      - name: "MYSQL_PASSWORD"
        value: "Test"
      - name: "MYSQL_DATABASE"
        value: "MysqlDB"
      - name: "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"
        value: "TFBern_3013"  
    ports:
    - containerPort: 3306
--- # Mysql Service definiert
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql-service
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 3306
  selector:
    name: mysql-pod

I also tried ping from wordpress to database and that worked without a problem. I just haven't figured out to ping from database to wordpress beacause I don't know how to install the ping package on bash-5.1

What is the exact error you get?  You should rarely if ever directly create Pods; for your application you probably want a Deployment, and for the database a StatefulSet.  Your client needs to target the Service's name, not the Pods' (there will frequently be multiple and without deterministic names), so maybe set WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=mysql-service?

It looks like you might be missing a Kubernetes service for your MySQL pod, which is crucial for enabling communication between your WordPress and MySQL pods. Here’s how to set up the service:
Why You Need a Service
A Kubernetes Service provides a stable IP address for your pods and handles load balancing. Without this, the hostname 'database' used in your WordPress configuration cannot be resolved, causing the connection error.
Update the MySQL Pod Configuration:
Add a label to your MySQL pod so it can be targeted by the service:
# Add under metadata in your database.yaml
 metadata
   name: database
   labels:
     app: database

Create a Service:
Save this as mysql-service.yaml:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: database
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 3306
    targetPort: 3306
  selector:
    app: database


Apply the Configuration:
Run these commands:
kubectl apply -f database.yaml
kubectl apply -f mysql-service.yaml



Then try again and you shouldn’t get the “Failed to establish database connection” error anymore.
If it persists, do post more details and I’ll share my thoughts.
UPDATE
Just saw that you have a mysql-service, so as David mentioned, set WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=mysql-service and you should be good.

It works now with following yaml files:
wordpress.yaml:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: wordpress
spec:
  containers:
  - name: app
    image: wordpress:latest
    env:
    - name: "WORDPRESS_DB_HOST"
      value: "mysql-service"  
    - name: "WORDPRESS_DB_NAME"
      value: "MysqlDB"
    - name: "WORDPRESS_DB_USER"
      value: "admin"
    - name: "WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD"
      value: "Test"
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80`

database.yaml:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: database
  labels: 
    name: mysql-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: database
    image: mysql:latest
    env:
      - name: "MYSQL_USER"
        value: "admin"
      - name: "MYSQL_PASSWORD"
        value: "Test"
      - name: "MYSQL_DATABASE"
        value: "MysqlDB"
      - name: "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"
        value: "Test"  
    ports:
    - containerPort: 3306
--- # Mysql Service definiert
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql-service
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 3306
  selector:
    name: mysql-pod


Awesome. Good to know you’re unblocked.

Welcome to SO! It might be helpful to expand your answer a bit to explain why this works, so people with a similar question in the future can learn from it.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
